# How to sum all the elements of an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, integer

So I'm making a GUI where basically the user inputs a series of numbers into an array list and I'm trying to make it so i can get the sum of all the numbers the add in. Here is what I have :

```
sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<numberlist.size(); i++){
    sum += numberlist.get(i);
}
Output.setText("The Sum of all the numbers is " + sum);
}
```

I get an error message that says:

```
inconvertable types. 
required : int 
found: java.lang.string
```

Comment: What do you think the error means?

Comment: You are passing the string but not the integer,try changing the code to retrieve the input.And please post your full code

Comment: GUIs typically require String to int conversion :)

Comment: I don't think we could really explain it much better than the error message does. It requires an `int`. You gave it a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm betting you have an `ArrayList<String>`. This means that your numbers are stored as a `String`. So what you should do is use an `ArrayList<Integer>` and then parse the strings you get with `Integer.parseInt(yourinputstring)` and then add that to the ArrayList.

Comment: Integer.parseInt(yourinputstring.trim()) will be safe to avoid numberformatexception in cases of unintentional or extra spaces

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Integer.parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) like so

```
for (int i=0; i<numberlist.size(); i++){
  sum += Integer.parseInt(numberlist.get(i));
}
```

Comment: better to add trim()  to avoid numberformatexception ,   so  sum += Integer.parseInt(numberlist.get(i).trim());

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your GUI takes user inputs as String list.

In this case Try:

```
sum+=Integer.parseInt(numberlist.get(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just from looking at this snippet, I would assume that you have to convert "numberlist.get(i)" to an int.

```
sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<numberlist.size(); i++){
    sum += Integer.parseInt(numberlist.get(i));
}
Output.setText("The Sum of all the numbers is " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to error:

> inconvertable types.
> required : int
> found: java.lang.string

you defined an ArrayList of String which contains inputed numbers, so to sum these numbers
firstly you need to convert the String of number to a number and then sum them:

1. if the values are Integer then try to use `Integer.parseInt()` or `Integer.valueOf()`
2. if the values are Double then try to use 'Double.parseDouble()' or 'Double.valueOf()'
3. `Long.parseLong()` or `Long.valueOf()`
4. [more details about number](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)

```
ArrayList<String> numberlist = new ArrayList<>();
numberlist.add("1");
numberlist.add("2");
numberlist.add("3");
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numberlist.size(); i++) {
    sum += Integer.valueOf(numberlist.get(i));
}
Output.setText("The Sum of all the numbers is " + sum);
```